# How to revert from Gtk3 to Gtk2 indicators in xfce4-panel?

Tags: 14.04, indicator, gtk3, xfce-panel, gtk-2

When with **Saucy**, I used this tutorial to have **gtk3 indicators** in `xfce4-panel`:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Xubuntu/Roadmap/Specifications/Saucy/Gtk3Indicators

Now I upgraded to **Trusty** and I see a messed up panel, so I'd like to revert to the original indicators. How can I do?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that you don't really want to revert to Gtk2 indicators, because you get Gtk3 indicators by default in Trusty and the Gtk2 ones will no longer work at all. The development work you installed in Saucy is now the default (but fixed up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you followed the steps to install development versions of xfce-panel and the indicator plugin, you built them from source, and `sudo make install` installed them into /usr/local.

In order to clean out that installation you need to manually delete those installed files. Unfortunately there is no way to do this automatically. However, what you can do is follow the installation steps again and observe what files it installs and then delete them by hand. You can semi-automate this by doing:

```
find /usr/local/ -mtime -1 -type f
```

This will list all files in /usr/local less than 1 day old, which should include all the installed files if you follow the installation steps again. You can also use `-delete` argument with find to delete all the found files, but **check first that the result is sane.**

**Edit:** Apparently, `sudo make uninstall` may work for this particular set of applications. If you still have the repositories where you built the software just run `sudo make uninstall` in each one. If not, you will need to go through the install steps again, skipping the `sudo make install` for each repository, and then running `sudo make uninstall` in all three at the end, after you have built everything.

Comment: why can't you post a list of such files? You have the gits as I linked the source tutorial.